# How can I output "temporarily" to the shell, like zsh tab completion does?

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, prompt

In `zsh` shell, when you hit Tab twice to get tab completion, your options are displayed below your prompt. But when you make a selection, the options disappear.

I have a little script that outputs passwords to stdout based on keyword search. The only problem is, after I've copied and pasted and I'm done, the passwords stay in the terminal. I would really like to implement this "temporary" output for my passwords script. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On any system that uses [terminfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo):

```
printf "The password is %s " "swordfish"
read -r line
tput cuu1; tput el
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to erase the password and quit, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to quit immediately. If your system uses [termcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap), use `tput up; tput ce`. This code assumes that the cursor is still on the line with the password by the time the user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for inadvertently showing me how to use string formatting!